# Defining Window Style Constants in VBA (0x00000000 vs &H000)

Tags: vba, winapi, dialog, constants, window-style

This might be a pretty basic question, but I've been searching and cannot find an explanation. 
I'm playing with API functions for dialog boxes in VBA and I want to declare constants for the Window Styles as defined here so I can try to use the CreateDialog API function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx

Normally I see windows constants in VBA defined as long types with a value something like `&H000` or something like that.  But, I can't find the `&H000` format value for these constants, I can only find the `0x00000000` format values.

For example, see the OpenFileName documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx) and scroll down to the flags.  The constant expressions are listed with values in the format `0x00000000`.  However, if we look at the CommonDialog constants [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259317(v=vs.60).aspx), we can see the same constants listed with their values in the format `&H000`.

So I guess I have at least three questions:
What do the 0x0000000 values represent?
What do the &H000 values represent?
Is their a way to convert between them?

Because I tried declaring `Public Const WS_BORDER as Long=0x00800000L` and I get a syntax area after the "x" saying expected end of statement.

Comment: That sounds simple enough.  However, the "L" at the end of the expression is still giving a syntax error.  E.g. I changed `Long=0x00800000L` to `Long=&H00800000L` and it is giving me a syntax error on the "L" saying expected end of statement

Comment: The `L` suffix is also a C idiom, just drop it in VBA: `Public Const WS_BORDER as Long = H&00800000`

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to do some reading.  I found [this](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/161304?ln=end) just before you posted and tried converting the L suffix to &, however it does the same thing as just dropping the L.  and I find it interesting that VB automatically converts `H&00800000` or `H&00800000&` to `&H800000`

Comment: &H is the VBA equivalent of 0x.  It signals VBA that the number will be hexadecimal.  You will be fine to enter it like that. The L is not part of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x...L` format is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx) for C++ (I believe it's the same in a few other languages).  The `0x` signifies that the number is hexadecimal, and the `L` signifies that it should be interpreted by the compiler as a `Long`.

The equivalent VBA syntax would be `&H...&` Where `&H` signifies hexadecimal and `&` signifies `Long`.

So for example, your statement:

```
Public Const WS_BORDER as Long = 0x00800000L
```

Should be:

```
Public Const WS_BORDER as Long = &H00800000&
```

Comment: I did try the `&H....&` format, but VBA automatically just shortens it as soon as I move off that line, which I thought was interesting.

Comment: VBA will get rid of the leading zeroes, but that's fine: it will still be the same number.